# Why this goroutine leaks?

Tags: go

I am reading 'Concurrency in Go' and have found this example of goroutine leaks:

```
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    doWork := func(strings <-chan string) <-chan interface{} {
        completed := make(chan interface{})
        go func() {
            defer fmt.Println("doWork exited.")
            defer close(completed)
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println("a")
            for s := range strings {
                fmt.Println(s)
            }
            fmt.Println("b")
        }()
        return completed
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    doWork(nil)
    fmt.Println("Waiting")
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

> The `strings` channel will never gets any strings written onto it, and the goroutine containing `doWork` will remain in memory for the life time of process.

I don't understand - why ?

How I understand this code:

- As `strings` is `nil` `range`-loop just skipped. As any range over `nil`:

  ```
  slice := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
  slice = nil
  for i := range slice {
     fmt.Println(i)
  }
  fmt.Println("Done")
  ```
- `fmt.Println("doWork exited.")` will be executed
- `close(completed)` will be executed

But I see it works like that. Why ?

Comment: Receive from a nil channel blocks forever. The range statement isn't skipped, it never terminates because the "channel" is never closed. https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As strings is nil range-loop just skipped.

This assumption is not correct. In Go, reading from a `nil` channel will always block. This is defined in the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) (thanks to @peterSO for digging out the link):

> Receiving from a nil channel blocks forever.

There's also [a post on the Go Design Patterns blog](https://www.godesignpatterns.com/2014/05/nil-channels-always-block.html) that further elaborates on this behaviour and highlights some cases in which it is useful.

Anyhow, this behaviour can easily be reproduced with a minimal example ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v-zLfWKDVgg)):

```
func main() {
    var s chan string
    <- s
}
```

This program will never finish (in the playground, it will crash with `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock`).

Because reading from a nil channel (in the case of your example, `strings`) will block (forever, since nothing can be written into a nil channel), the `doWork` goroutine will never complete, and thus, leak.

Comment: "In Go, reading from a nil channel will always block. I haven't been able to find any official documentation on this behaviour." [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec): Receiving from a nil channel blocks forever. [Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator).

Comment: @peterSO Thanks for providing the link to the spec! I've updated the answer accordingly.